# How to send Jira to Slack channel "Ready for QA" notification

Tags: jira, slack

I need to post Jira notifications to a slack channel. The condition is any Jira ticket that moves to "Ready for QA" status should be notified in the slack channel. I setup a webhook already where JQL is set to Status Ready for QA. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom event notification create an event and then create a post function in your transition before the Ready for QA status change. please check this link to see how to configure it : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/configure-a-custom-event-notification-for-a-specific-jira-workflow-transition-or-status-720831525.html